# Java: generrate a infinite sinusoid tone on sound speaker

Tags: java, audio

I am trying to use Java Audio API to generate a stereo sound with two sin waves with distinct frequencies, but neither I can use a dual channel system, but also my tone, for some reason, interrupts and restarts while playing.

My source code:

```
public class GeradorSinal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

int fs = 48000;
AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(fs, 8, 1, true, true);
SourceDataLine line;
Thread generator;
boolean parar = false;
byte[] senoid = new byte[1];

/**
 * Creates new form GeradorSinal
 */
public GeradorSinal() {
    initComponents();
    try {
        line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
        line.open(af, fs);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static double scale(
        double x,
        double old_min, double old_max,
        double new_min, double new_max) {
    double old_range = old_max - old_min;
    double new_range = new_max - new_min;
    return new_min + (x - old_min) * new_range / old_range;
}                     

private void bt_gerarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    generator = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long t = 0;
            long f = Long.parseLong(ln_freq.getText());
            line.start();
            while (!parar) {
                senoid[0] = (byte) scale(Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * f * t++ / fs),
                        -1.0, 1.0, Byte.MIN_VALUE, Byte.MAX_VALUE);
                line.write(senoid, 0, 1);
            }
            line.stop();
        }
    });
    generator.start();
}                                        

private void bt_pararActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:;
    parar = true;
    try {
        generator.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    parar = false;
}                                        

private void bt_salvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("testes.txt", true);
        try (BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(fstream)) {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            fbw.write(dateFormat.format(date));
            fbw.write("\t");
            fbw.write(ln_freq.getText());
            fbw.write("\t");
            fbw.write(String.valueOf(1.2 * Double.parseDouble(ln_freq.getText())));
            fbw.write("\t");
            fbw.write(ln_volume.getText());
            fbw.newLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Try generating a whole array of samples instead of writing just 1 sample at a time.

Comment: I have tried, same problem.

Comment: Notice that the stream loops infinitely, which is desired

Comment: Typically sound API like this deals better with sending a buffer instead of trying to do it 1 sample at a time. Try a buffer of at least 500 or 1000 samples. Also, although this will not affect the sound choppiness, your `parar` variable needs to be volatile or the `generator` thread has no obligation to see it change.

Comment: I see you're also opening the line with a buffer size that's different from what you're writing to it. This could also be a problem. Honestly I am not sure what happens when you try to do this. The docs don't cover it. Try opening the line without a suggested buffer size or opening it with the same size as you are writing to it.

Comment: I believe everything is working fine now. Thanks